# Uncorrelatedness and Chebyshev-like Inequality

Tags: probability, random-variables

Two bounded, zero-mean random variables $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, i.e. $\mathbb{E}[XY] = 0$. Can we say $ Pr (X+Y < 0 | X < 0) $ is not zero ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample. Let $(X,Y)$ take with probability $1/4$ each the values $(-2,3),(-1,2),(1,-18),(2,13)$.